# Liferay Login page redirect

Tags: java

Hi every one i am new to liferay i ve developed my own page and when i click sign-in In main page i want to redirect to my custom page instead going to default home page.. can anyone pls suggest me how to do this where i should redirect it thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Default Landing Page in the Control Panel:

Portal -> Settings -> General -> Navigation

Or, in the portal-ext.properties, set:

```
default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/home
```