# Liferay changing the default redirect page when a does not have the specific role

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

This is basically two question? First i was wonder how to change the page liferay redirects when a user tries to access a page that has Power User view permissions. Liferay by default points to localhost:web/guest/home where they have their login page. On my application i have a different login in page and i want to redirect to the following page. I was browsing the web and found out that by setting `auth.login.site.url=/whereiwontittopoint` should actualy redirect me there. However it does not. I'm using Liferay  6.0.6 Community Editions. Has anyone done this? Is this the right way or this need to be done with a hook?

My other question is the following. I want to have a custom role on some pages. And i want when a user does not have that specfic role to be redirect to a totaly different page not the default login. I'm fairly sure this can be done by using the hook on some service but for some reason i can not identify this service.

EDIT
Ok for the first question i solved the issues. For the second question the answers i got here were not what i was looking for probably because i didn't post the question correctly. This is a full scenario of what i have done and what i need to do:

First of all i changed the /web/guest path that's on every liferay page to web/somthing/ this might not play a crucial role but the problems(some of the problems) started when that happend. THe over all idea is the following. I'm using spring mvc to create the application. I have created a backend to my application from where the admin can create pages for other users to see(This is not done by going to the control panel of liferay and adding a page but through the logic of the application). Once a page is created depending on some logic i create a role for that certain page(customer role also through code not the liferay admin). Some of the users are given this role if the satisfy some criteria and some are not. Here my problem arises, once a user that is loged in to my application tries to access a page (by inputting a direct URL in the browser to the page) that requres the view permision of the role i create for that page and the user does not have the appropriate role he gets redirect to lets say localhost/web/(username)/home a personal page and for some reason on that page by default from liferay he is able to view personal data(user name) of all other users of the application. My question is how through code to handle the redirection that happens of the above scenario. 
I have tried on one attempt to actualy hook the servlet.service.events.pre action and before the user access that page to check if he has the appropriate permisions and actualy change his request. So far i have some issues but i can resolve them but this approach is not what i not rly what i am looking for because this action is executed before every single request on the application( and the page handling is just small part of that application) which means i will have a lot of code executing for no reason. I was wondering if there are any ways to add where the exception will redirect when i create the role? If not what action should i hook that will help me solve this scenario but with out the unneeded extrea trafic that i am creating with hooking servlet.service.events.pre action?

Answer (score 2):

For the second stuff a bit hacky way could be as follows

1) Define set of roles against which you want to check in portal-ext.properties. You can add some property like **my.super.secret.roles=rolename1,rolename2**

2) Add a property for a redirect page url in portal-ext.properties so that you can redirect user there.

3)Add a custom attribute for Layout named **checkForSecretRoles** which has to be boolean and visible on Page. This will show you a checkbox in Manage page for each page, so that an admin can easily check or uncheck the value

4)Add a condition in your theme (portal_normal.vm) to check if the page has a check for secret role and then check the users role falls in any of the roles defined in portal-ext.properties. If yes then issue a redirect to the page specified by your custom redirect page url property

Answer (score 1):

1. For your first question, it should work -

   ```
   auth.forward.last.paths=/sign-in
   ```

   sign-in would be your page name
2. The answer for your second question is, you have to create a Hook extending Action and made the below entry in your portal-ext.properties.

   ```
   login.events.post=com.liferay.portal.events.LoginPostAction,com.liferay.portal.events.CustomLandingPageAction
   ```

There is a lot of information you can found on forum about how to use this property.

Answer (score 0):

for 1. set `default.landing.page.path=/whereiwontittopoint` in portal.properties, see [Liferay Login page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920970/liferay-login-page-redirect)

for 2. create a hook, set `servlet.service.events.post=com.my.action.MyAction` and impliment this action, at this point you can redirect user to another page.

Comment: You must have misunderstood me. The answer u posted for my first question is how to set a different landing page. I was asking how to change where liferay redirects for login. I solved that one, i was making a mistake and was supposed to use auth.login.url = instead of the one i used.

Comment: For the second question the, that action will execute after every single request which is extreamly expensive to have in production. I was asking if there is a way when i define a custom role and add it to a page, if i can also define what liferay will do if a user that has not acquired that role tries to access the page that request that role.

Comment: You can try to override error page event `servlet.service.events.pre.error.page`